# How to open local HTML page in native android browser (not in webview)?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a FORM html file in "asset" folder. I want to open it in native browser like this,

```
String dataUri = "file:///android_asset/testform.html";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(dataUri));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

How to open it in separate browser window and not in webview.
I don't want to display it as in-app with webview.

I want to open browser, because my URLs returns PDF or HTML files. The HTML gets loaded in webview properly but the PDF doesn't open in webview. The data (HTML or PDF) is dynamic. Hence I want to open a browser window so that it can be handled native way.

Comment: what is happening when you run this code?

Comment: The webpage has to accessible for it to be loaded in the browser. Your apps assets cannot be accessed by the browser.

Comment: I am getting error while opening the browser that, "can not open testform.html, is in invalid format"



**Update**
At run time I created a file in public directory "DOWNLOADS" and use that HTML file so that it can be accessed by browser, but same error persists.